# What are all the NSURLErrorDomain errors with equivalent HTTP status codes?

Tags: ios, cocoa, http-status-codes, foundation, nserror

In the documentation for [NSURLErrorDomain errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes) the description for NSURLErrorBadServerResponse is listed as:

> Returned when the URL Loading system receives bad data from the
>   server.
>
> This is equivalent to the “500 Server Error” message sent by HTTP
>   servers.

Are there other NSURLErrorDomain errors with equivalent HTTP status codes? For example, is NSURLErrorTimedOut equivalent to 408 Request Timeout?

Answer (score 3):

Those values are defined in NSURLError.h. If you type `NSURLErrorDomain` into Spotlight searchon your Mac, it will find respective file somewhere, in my case inside `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/..`.

Updated URL for the URL Loading System Error Codes on Apple's Developer Site: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes?language=occ

Answer (score 1):

(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/)

To get the http status code cast the returned `NSURLResponse` to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and the `statusCode` property will have it.

Ex:

```
let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
```

For Apple's documentation go to [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/) and enter the error name in the upper-right search field. Also you can select the language and under *Options* you can select the "Deployment Target", and "Auto-expand all symbols", check "Auto-expand all symbols".
[image]

For `NSURLErrorBadServerResponse` click "On This Page" and enter NSURLErrorBadServerResponse. Then click on the yellow highlighted name un der the search field.
[image]
You will be at the section: These values are returned as the error code property of an NSError object with the domain “NSURLErrorDomain”.
Scroll down (of use Safari search) to NSURLErrorBadServerResponse

```
NSURLErrorBadServerResponse
Returned when the URL Loading system receives bad data from the server.

This is equivalent to the “500 Server Error” message sent by HTTP servers.

Available in OS X v10.2 and later.
```

Other error sites that may br useful:

[HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)
[Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: I'm looking for a list of matching error codes to status codes and not code.

Comment: I can find HTTP status codes. I can't find a list of status codes that match up to NSURLErrorDomain errors.

Comment: Updated the answer with information about Apple's "Foundation Constants Reference"